# Bottom align centered-horizontal list in header div // keep non-header div at top when div reaches top of chrome

Tags: html, css

I am beginning to create my first website using my new codeacademy skills. I would like help with two items, answers will be greatly appreciated

1. Bottom-aligning centered horizontal list

   I need to bring the ul li element to the bottom of my header div. I have tried to use margin-top but that brings down my header div, and not just the list
2. Keeping div at top of webpage

   I need to keep a div at the top of my webpage when it reaches the top (ie, div is not header). This div is a lower iv down the webpage, and will eventually be a picture. I have tried position:fixed, but this doesnt work (example: http://www.stantec.com/) Cant find a way w/o using jQuery!!

Code: main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>Home Page</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">

        <ul id="headerMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="mainPhoto">    </div>

    <div id="mainScrollUp">    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my stylesheet.css

```
<--stylesheet.css-->
.header {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}

#headerMenu {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color:black;

}

#headerMenu li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

#headerMenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 3rem;
}

#headerMenu li a:hover {
  color: lightgray;
}

#mainPhoto {
  height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: bisque;

}

#mainScrollUp {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: 1. `padding-top:50px` 2. I cant see anything in your code, which div is this and can you explain a little more?

Comment: 2. If you want a div that is lower on a page to remain at the top once it has scrolled to that position (and stay there even you when keep scrolling down), then you will have to use javascript (or jQuery like you mentioned) to change the CSS "position" attribute for it once it reaches the top of the page. Is this the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: @MikeThomson yes, this is. Should I learn jQuery or java script then, not just for this but what will be more useful

Comment: @MattEm Seeing how jQuery is built on top of and for use with javascript, it will do you a lot of good to learn javascript first, then move on to jQuery. If you learn javascript, then there won't even be a learning curve to get using jQuery because it is incredibly intuitive for people who know javascript. You will end up using both a lot throughout you web development endeavors.

Comment: @MikeThomson codeacademy says that learning jquery first is preferred and easier...?

Comment: @MattEm Yes, jQuery is easier. A lot of people would argue that jQuery should be learned first _because_ it's easier, but I disagree because then you don't learn the reasons why jQuery is valuable and where it is overkill. Learning jQuery first will not help much with learning javascript, but learning javascript will make jQuery very simple and you will know the fundamentals of both. You will definitely use both a lot. Same age-old argument of bottom-up vs. top-down learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1 add this to your css:

```
.header{
display:table;
}
#headerMenu{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

For question 2 I need to know which color div you want left at the top under the header.

This is an example but it DOES require jquery. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/frhhv2c6/2/)

Comment: in fact, the display:table-cell just makes width of div half

Comment: actually, if you use display:table; it works. wrong anser but pointed me in right direction, so thanks @kinburn101

Comment: @MattEm If you click through to his DEMO link, you'll see that it works with the jQuery code he added.

Comment: @MikeThomson thanks for the tips with java/jquery. i cant get the demo code to work in my code tho.. any tips there? it does work as you had me notice

Comment: @MattEm To use jQuery, you'll need to import the jQuery script, such as doing it in the <head> tags with: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` Then the demo code should work for you (you'll also have to put `<script></script>` tags around the javascript code, the DEMO above does it for you so you don't see them).

Comment: My mistake on adding `display:table-cell;` to `.header` it should be `display:table;` as I think you figured out. Adding a jquery library is quite easy as @Mike Thomson mentioned. If you have any troubles post them here.

Comment: If this has put you on the right track please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Kinburn101 thanks, kinburn, must have unclicked the check :)